# What are the advantages of a multi-site installation?

Tags: multisite

I am working with an organisation that is already using CiviCRM in English. It is developing with teams in a number of countries each of which is recruiting supporters, running training events and working in a different language. We now have Spanish, French, German and Finnish speaking teams. What advantages would we gain from a multisite installation?

The current English installation of CiviCRM is in a Joomla environment.

Answer (score 3):

CiviCRM multisite allows you to have several organizations sharing the same instance of CiviCRM, but only a superuser can see the data across all sites.

The most common example is an organization with multiple chapters.  You mention your organization is active in different countries.  If:

- You require that users from country A not be able to see contacts entered in country B;
- Users in a "head office" need to see contacts from multiple countries in a single place;

Then multisite is for you.

Comment: In addition to what Jon said above, CiviCRM multisite also is handy if you have different chapters that want to be streamlined with the parent org but still allow for some flexibility. For instance, each chapter can have it's own accounts for things such as email or SMS service but still use the same infrastructure. There's also some out of the box permissioning with the multisite extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/multisite-permissioning.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this issue and finally found the below link it's about WordPress and I think it could be helpful.
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/

Comment: This is about WordPress multisite, not CiviCRM multisite.  I assume the question author is asking about CiviCRM multisite.

Comment: Regarding a CiviCRM multisite the CiviCRM site has complete guidance for Multi-site installation https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/multi-site/